# When is $f+g$ guaranteed non-injective for $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^n$ periodic?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, periodic-functions

Let $n\geq1$ be a fixed integer. Let $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ with irrational ratio. If $f:\mathbb{R}/(a)\to\mathbb{R}^n$ and $g:\mathbb{R}/(b)\to\mathbb{R}^n$, then how many of $f$ and $g$ need to be continuous to guarantee that $f+g$ is not injective?

For $n=1$ I know the answer is one, and for $n\geq4$ I know non-injectivity cannot be implied by continuity, but I don't know the answer for $n\in\{2,3\}$.

To show that $f+g$ can be injective if $f$ and $g$ are continuous and $n=4$, define $f(x):=(\sin(2\pi x/a),\cos(2\pi x/a),0,0)$ and $g(x):=(0,0,\sin(2\pi x/b),\cos(2\pi x/b))$. Then $(f+g)(x)=(f+g)(y)$ only if $f(x)=f(y)$ and $g(x)=g(y)$ only if $x\equiv y\ (\mbox{mod}\ a)$ and $x\equiv y\ (\mbox{mod}\ b)$ only if $x=y$.

To show that $f+g$ can be injective if neither are continuous and $n=1$, let $B$ be a $\mathbb{Q}$-linear basis of $\mathbb{R}$. Since $|B|=|\mathbb{R}|$, there is an injection from the disjoint union of $\mathbb{R}/(a)$ and $\mathbb{R}/(b)$ to $B$, which we use to define $f:\mathbb{R}/(a)\to B$ and $g:\mathbb{R}/(b)\to B$. It follows that $(f+g)(x)=(f+g)(y)$ only if $x\equiv y\ (\mbox{mod}\ a)$ and $x\equiv y\ (\mbox{mod}\ b)$ only if $x=y$.

If $n=2$ then I also have a construction that does not use the axiom of choice. Let $f(x)=(x,0)$ for $x\in[0,a)$ and $g(x)=(0,x)$ for $x\in[0,b)$. Then $(f+g)(x)=(f+g)(y)$ only if $x\equiv y\ (\mbox{mod}\ a)$ and $x\equiv y\ (\mbox{mod}\ b)$ only if $x=y$.

To show that $f+g$ can not be injective if $f$ is continuous and $n=1$, note that $\mathbb{R}/(a)$ is compact, so $f$ attains a maximum and minimum. It follows that $h:\mathbb{R}/(a)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $h(x)=f(x)-f(x+b)$ is neither strictly positive everywhere nor strictly negative everywhere. By the intermediate value theorem, there exists $x\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $h(x)=0$, so $f(x)=f(x+b)$. Then $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)=f(x+b)+g(x+b)=(f+g)(x+b)$, so $f+g$ is not injective.

Comment: weird&stupid question but i have urge to ask it for some reason: do u have a proof that the answer is independent of $a,b$?

Comment: Good point, not a stupid question at all. To be fair, I kind of assumed $a$ and $b$ to not be fixed, so if you have a proof that $f,g$ continuous imply $f+g$ not injective for specific values of $a$ and $b$, that would not solve the problem.

Comment: can u comment (again) on why you think for $n=2$, $f,g$ continuous implies $f+g$ not injective? maybe we can turn it into a proof

Comment: The map $(x,y)\mapsto f(x)+g(y):\mathbb{R}/(a)\times\mathbb{R}/(b)\to\mathbb{R}^2$ continuously maps the torus into the plane. The map $x\mapsto f(x)+g(x):\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is thus a composition of an injective map from $\mathbb{R}$ into the torus with dense image and a map from the torus into the plane. Intuitively, the map from the torus into the plane is two-to-one almost everywhere, so I expect on such a structured dense subset the map can not be injective.

Comment: Can you explain this to me: "Intuitively, the map from the torus into the plane is two-to-one almost everywhere". I know you might not be being rigorous, but I just don't get this at all.

Comment: Come to think of it, it is more like "even-to-one" almost everywhere. I am not being rigorous, because I don't know how to describe, let alone prove, this rigorously. But as an example, if you do a flat projection of the torus, you get some kind of ring. The projection is two-to-one in the interior, and one-to-one on the boundary. If you do a vertical projection, then it is two-to-one or four-to-one almost everywhere, and one-to-one or three-to-one on some curves.

Answer (score 2):

For $n=3$, the functions
$$
f(x) = \big( \cos(2\pi x/a), \sin(2\pi x/a), 0 \big), \quad
g(x) = \big( 0, \sin(2\pi x/b), \cos(2\pi x/b) \big)
$$
are both continuous, but we can show that $f+g$ is injective as follows.

Suppose $(f+g)(x)=(f+g)(y)$. From the first coordinate we see that $x\equiv\pm y\pmod a$, while from the third coordinate we see that $x\equiv\pm y\pmod b$. If the two $\pm$ signs are the same, then we immediately get $x=y$ as in the OP.

So, without loss of generality, suppose that $x\equiv y\pmod a$ and $x\equiv- y\pmod b$. A little algebra shows that there exist integers $j$ and $k$ such that
$$
x=\frac{jb-ka}2 \quad\text{and}\quad y=\frac{jb+ka}2.
$$
From the second coordinate of $(f+g)(x)=(f+g)(y)$, we see that $\sin(2\pi x/a)+\sin(2\pi x/b)=\sin(2\pi y/a)+\sin(2\pi y/b)$, which becomes
$$
\sin \left(\frac{\pi  a k}{b}-\pi  l\right)+\sin \left(\frac{\pi  a k}{b}+\pi 
   l\right)+\sin \left(\pi  k-\frac{\pi  b l}{a}\right)+\sin \left(\frac{\pi  b l}{a}+\pi
    k\right) = 0,
$$
or, after using trig addition formulas and $\sin(\pi k)=0$ and $|\cos (\pi  l)|=1$,
$$
\sin   \left(\frac{\pi  a k}{b}\right)=0.
$$
But this would imply that $ka/b$ is an integer, a contradiction unless $k=0$ and hence $x=y$.

Comment: A probably easier way to do this calculation is to calculate $f(x)-f(x+kb)$.

Comment: For $n=2$, I feel like injectivity is possible if $f$ is continuous. Maybe an example will work where $f$ just parametrizes a circle in $\Bbb R^2$, while $g$ is of the form $g(x) = (g_1(x),0)$; I feel that one could choose the values of $g_1$ on $\Bbb R/(b)$ from a Hamel basis, where for each $t\pmod b$ one would need to avoid a countable number of bad choices that could cause a coincidence in $f+g$.

Comment: Very nice! I was trying almost the same example, but could not show that it is injective, but this is a very reasonable proof that it is indeed injective. So the only unsolved case is $n=2$. I personally suspect that the answer is two.